# Renice: How to change all threads?

Tags: linux, multi-threading, scheduler, nice

When I `renice` a multithreaded process in Ubuntu 10.04, then view the results in `top`, it seems that only the main thread actually gets reniced.  All the other threads retain their old nice value.  What's the easiest way to renice all threads in a process instead of just the main thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
renice +/-n -g gid
```

Where `gid` is the process group id which you can find with 
`ps -Aj`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by zhihui's answer, what I actually used:

```
renice -n <niceness> -p `ps --no-heading -Lo tid <PID>`
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command can set the nice value to +15 for all threads in process "procid":

```
ps --no-heading -Lj <procid> | awk '{system("renice +15 "$4)}'
```